# Files are not found in server, but they are uploaded

Tags: centos7

I am trying to install opencart TVS on VPS server which is running Centos 7. I have used some tutorials, done everything like they said. Opencart files are uploaded into server but however install/index.php file is not found. 
So I tried to upload an image to server and see if it shows or not. Nope, it does not show.

I have installed Centos Panel. Created account over there. Created database there also. The problem that I cannot see uploaded files and I think that install/index.php is not shown due to the same problem.

Apache: Apache version: Apache/2.4.39
MySQL version: 10.1.38-MariaDB
Server IP: http://141.136.44.45

File is listed in Home/USERNAME/public_html/
So as understand the file should be reached like: http://141.136.44.45/1.png (it is uploaded in Home/USERNAME/public_html/1.png